# Get Height from Floor Level React Native

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to get the height from the floor level in React Native? Assume I'm in the 2nd floor of a building. I want to get the current height I'm holding the device from the floor level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location

this library allows us to retrieve the altitude of the phone and an index of accuracy. 
ps: getting altitude of a mobile phone is never very accurate.